# What is entitlement key for NSWorkspace's - (void)showSearchResultsForQueryString method?

Tags: cocoa, sandbox

I couldn't find entitlement key for NSWorkSpace's showSearchResultsForQueryString anywhere including apple developer forum.
Who can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Ideally "showSearchResultsForQueryString" should work like "openURL" method within sandboxed application as well.
It was sdk bug that this method was denied within sandboxed application.